# mongorestore does absolutely nothing

Tags: mongodb

I want to quickly restore my earlier backuped db.
In order to accomplish that task I used the following command:

`mongorestore --drop -d awesome_db -c awesome_collection dump/awesome_db/awesome_collection.bson`

What is wrong with it? Definitely something went amiss cos it just did absolutely nothing and did not give me any error information, no tips no hints no nothing.

EDIT:

I've just tried issuing the same command but adding the port number for the master node and the host which is localhost in my case.

Here is the log.

```
tester@tester:~$ mongorestore --drop -d testfats_db -c test_test dump/fats_db/test_result.bson --host 127.0.0.1 --port 40002 -vvvvv
2018-09-19T12:04:54.450+0000    checking options
2018-09-19T12:04:55.314+0000        dumping with object check disabled
2018-09-19T12:04:55.314+0000    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2018-09-19T12:04:55.978+0000    connected to node type: replset
2018-09-19T12:04:56.111+0000    using write concern: w='majority', j=false, fsync=false, wtimeout=0
2018-09-19T12:04:56.284+0000    mongorestore target is a file, not a directory
2018-09-19T12:04:56.284+0000    setting number of insertions workers to number of parallel collections (4)
2018-09-19T12:04:56.284+0000    checking for collection data in dump/fats_db/test_result.bson
2018-09-19T12:04:56.284+0000    reading collection test_test for database testfats_db from dump/fats_db/test_result.bson
2018-09-19T12:04:56.285+0000    scanning directory test_result.bson for metadata
2018-09-19T12:04:56.285+0000    found metadata for collection at dump/fats_db/test_result.metadata.json
2018-09-19T12:04:56.285+0000    enqueued collection 'testfats_db.test_test'
2018-09-19T12:04:56.285+0000    finalizing intent manager with multi-database longest task first prioritizer
2018-09-19T12:04:56.285+0000    restoring up to 4 collections in parallel
2018-09-19T12:04:56.303+0000    starting restore routine with id=3
2018-09-19T12:04:56.303+0000    starting restore routine with id=1
2018-09-19T12:04:56.303+0000    ending restore routine with id=1, no more work to do
2018-09-19T12:04:56.303+0000    starting restore routine with id=0
2018-09-19T12:04:56.304+0000    ending restore routine with id=0, no more work to do
2018-09-19T12:04:56.304+0000    starting restore routine with id=2
2018-09-19T12:04:56.304+0000    ending restore routine with id=2, no more work to do
2018-09-19T12:04:57.680+0000    dropping collection testfats_db.test_test before restoring
2018-09-19T12:04:59.056+0000    reading metadata for testfats_db.test_test from dump/fats_db/test_result.metadata.json
2018-09-19T12:04:59.129+0000    creating collection testfats_db.test_test using options from metadata
2018-09-19T12:04:59.129+0000    using collection options: bson.D{bson.DocElem{Name:"idIndex", Value:mongorestore.IndexDocument{Options:bson.M{"name":"_id_", "ns":"testfats_db.test_test"}, Key:bson.D{bson.DocElem{Name:"_id", Value:1}}, PartialFilterExpression:bson.D(nil)}}}
2018-09-19T12:05:00.982+0000    restoring testfats_db.test_test from dump/fats_db/test_result.bson
2018-09-19T12:05:00.985+0000    using 4 insertion workers
2018-09-19T12:05:03.589+0000    [........................]  testfats_db.test_test  7.96MB/714MB  (1.1%)
2018-09-19T12:05:06.450+0000    [........................]  testfats_db.test_test  7.96MB/714MB  (1.1%)
2018-09-19T12:05:09.451+0000    [........................]  testfats_db.test_test  9.57MB/714MB  (1.3%)
2018-09-19T12:05:12.450+0000    [........................]  testfats_db.test_test  27.9MB/714MB  (3.9%)
2018-09-19T12:05:15.451+0000    [#.......................]  testfats_db.test_test  39.6MB/714MB  (5.5%)
2018-09-19T12:05:18.450+0000    [#.......................]  testfats_db.test_test  54.0MB/714MB  (7.6%)
2018-09-19T12:05:21.451+0000    [##......................]  testfats_db.test_test  67.3MB/714MB  (9.4%)
2018-09-19T12:05:24.451+0000    [##......................]  testfats_db.test_test  77.2MB/714MB  (10.8%)
2018-09-19T12:05:27.451+0000    [###.....................]  testfats_db.test_test  93.1MB/714MB  (13.0%)
2018-09-19T12:05:30.450+0000    [###.....................]  testfats_db.test_test  104MB/714MB  (14.5%)
2018-09-19T12:05:33.451+0000    [###.....................]  testfats_db.test_test  117MB/714MB  (16.4%)
2018-09-19T12:05:36.450+0000    [####....................]  testfats_db.test_test  130MB/714MB  (18.2%)
2018-09-19T12:05:39.450+0000    [####....................]  testfats_db.test_test  144MB/714MB  (20.2%)
2018-09-19T12:05:42.451+0000    [#####...................]  testfats_db.test_test  154MB/714MB  (21.6%)
2018-09-19T12:05:45.451+0000    [#####...................]  testfats_db.test_test  161MB/714MB  (22.6%)
2018-09-19T12:05:48.451+0000    [#####...................]  testfats_db.test_test  173MB/714MB  (24.2%)
2018-09-19T12:05:51.450+0000    [######..................]  testfats_db.test_test  188MB/714MB  (26.3%)
2018-09-19T12:05:54.451+0000    [######..................]  testfats_db.test_test  196MB/714MB  (27.5%)
2018-09-19T12:05:57.450+0000    [#######.................]  testfats_db.test_test  209MB/714MB  (29.3%)
2018-09-19T12:06:00.450+0000    [#######.................]  testfats_db.test_test  220MB/714MB  (30.8%)
2018-09-19T12:06:03.451+0000    [#######.................]  testfats_db.test_test  228MB/714MB  (31.9%)
2018-09-19T12:06:06.450+0000    [#######.................]  testfats_db.test_test  237MB/714MB  (33.2%)
2018-09-19T12:06:09.451+0000    [########................]  testfats_db.test_test  246MB/714MB  (34.5%)
2018-09-19T12:06:12.451+0000    [########................]  testfats_db.test_test  259MB/714MB  (36.3%)
2018-09-19T12:06:15.451+0000    [#########...............]  testfats_db.test_test  273MB/714MB  (38.3%)
2018-09-19T12:06:18.450+0000    [#########...............]  testfats_db.test_test  287MB/714MB  (40.2%)
2018-09-19T12:06:21.451+0000    [#########...............]  testfats_db.test_test  290MB/714MB  (40.6%)
2018-09-19T12:06:24.451+0000    [##########..............]  testfats_db.test_test  305MB/714MB  (42.7%)
2018-09-19T12:06:27.450+0000    [##########..............]  testfats_db.test_test  315MB/714MB  (44.1%)
2018-09-19T12:06:30.450+0000    [##########..............]  testfats_db.test_test  315MB/714MB  (44.1%)
2018-09-19T12:06:33.450+0000    [##########..............]  testfats_db.test_test  324MB/714MB  (45.4%)
2018-09-19T12:06:36.450+0000    [###########.............]  testfats_db.test_test  338MB/714MB  (47.4%)
2018-09-19T12:06:39.450+0000    [###########.............]  testfats_db.test_test  346MB/714MB  (48.5%)
2018-09-19T12:06:42.450+0000    [###########.............]  testfats_db.test_test  355MB/714MB  (49.7%)
2018-09-19T12:06:46.722+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  362MB/714MB  (50.7%)
2018-09-19T12:06:48.883+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  362MB/714MB  (50.7%)
2018-09-19T12:06:51.812+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  362MB/714MB  (50.7%)
2018-09-19T12:06:54.529+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  362MB/714MB  (50.7%)
2018-09-19T12:06:57.450+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  370MB/714MB  (51.8%)
2018-09-19T12:07:00.450+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  370MB/714MB  (51.8%)
2018-09-19T12:07:03.450+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  370MB/714MB  (51.8%)
2018-09-19T12:07:06.451+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  378MB/714MB  (53.0%)
2018-09-19T12:07:09.450+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  378MB/714MB  (53.0%)
2018-09-19T12:07:13.110+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  378MB/714MB  (53.0%)
2018-09-19T12:07:15.450+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  378MB/714MB  (53.0%)
2018-09-19T12:07:18.450+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  378MB/714MB  (53.0%)
2018-09-19T12:07:22.893+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:07:24.527+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:09:12.292+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:10:01.577+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:10:55.756+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:10:57.601+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:10:57.601+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:10:57.601+0000    [############............]  testfats_db.test_test  386MB/714MB  (54.1%)
2018-09-19T12:10:57.850+0000    error: operation was interrupted
2018-09-19T12:10:57.851+0000    error: operation was interrupted
2018-09-19T12:10:57.851+0000    error: operation was interrupted
2018-09-19T12:11:09.239+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  389MB/714MB  (54.5%)
2018-09-19T12:11:15.025+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  393MB/714MB  (55.1%)
2018-09-19T12:11:16.888+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  394MB/714MB  (55.1%)
2018-09-19T12:11:17.932+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:17.932+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:17.932+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:17.932+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:20.643+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  394MB/714MB  (55.3%)
2018-09-19T12:11:21.481+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  396MB/714MB  (55.4%)
2018-09-19T12:11:24.477+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:24.477+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:24.477+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:24.478+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:24.478+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  402MB/714MB  (56.3%)
2018-09-19T12:11:26.330+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:26.557+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:26.557+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:26.738+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:27.824+0000    [#############...........]  testfats_db.test_test  411MB/714MB  (57.6%)
2018-09-19T12:11:28.490+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:28.535+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:28.535+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:28.579+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:30.193+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:30.450+0000    [##############..........]  testfats_db.test_test  425MB/714MB  (59.5%)
2018-09-19T12:11:30.615+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:30.661+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:31.237+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:33.920+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:33.921+0000    [##############..........]  testfats_db.test_test  432MB/714MB  (60.5%)
2018-09-19T12:11:34.786+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:35.261+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:35.276+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:36.450+0000    [##############..........]  testfats_db.test_test  438MB/714MB  (61.3%)
2018-09-19T12:11:36.732+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:37.741+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:37.943+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:37.943+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:38.899+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:39.211+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:39.212+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:39.213+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:39.450+0000    [###############.........]  testfats_db.test_test  452MB/714MB  (63.4%)
2018-09-19T12:11:40.566+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:42.222+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:42.224+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:42.450+0000    [###############.........]  testfats_db.test_test  460MB/714MB  (64.4%)
2018-09-19T12:11:42.608+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:42.988+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:43.398+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:43.399+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:43.674+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:43.838+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:45.238+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:45.242+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:45.450+0000    [###############.........]  testfats_db.test_test  475MB/714MB  (66.5%)
2018-09-19T12:11:45.670+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:45.880+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:46.557+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:47.318+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:47.684+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:47.711+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:48.450+0000    [################........]  testfats_db.test_test  485MB/714MB  (68.0%)
2018-09-19T12:11:49.858+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:50.288+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:51.450+0000    [################........]  testfats_db.test_test  492MB/714MB  (68.9%)
2018-09-19T12:11:51.939+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:51.940+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:55.075+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:55.675+0000    [################........]  testfats_db.test_test  496MB/714MB  (69.5%)
2018-09-19T12:11:56.124+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:56.410+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:57.169+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:57.450+0000    [################........]  testfats_db.test_test  502MB/714MB  (70.3%)
2018-09-19T12:11:58.358+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:58.430+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:58.580+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:59.190+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:11:59.777+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:00.259+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:00.450+0000    [#################.......]  testfats_db.test_test  514MB/714MB  (72.0%)
2018-09-19T12:12:01.269+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:01.629+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:03.125+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:03.180+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:03.310+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:03.313+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:03.450+0000    [#################.......]  testfats_db.test_test  525MB/714MB  (73.5%)
2018-09-19T12:12:03.578+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:03.680+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:04.639+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:04.724+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:05.755+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:06.009+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:06.613+0000    [##################......]  testfats_db.test_test  537MB/714MB  (75.2%)
2018-09-19T12:12:08.473+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:08.830+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:09.102+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:09.450+0000    [##################......]  testfats_db.test_test  544MB/714MB  (76.1%)
2018-09-19T12:12:09.975+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:10.954+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:11.317+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:12.165+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:12.440+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:12.450+0000    [##################......]  testfats_db.test_test  552MB/714MB  (77.3%)
2018-09-19T12:12:14.108+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:14.372+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:14.747+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:14.863+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:15.450+0000    [##################......]  testfats_db.test_test  561MB/714MB  (78.6%)
2018-09-19T12:12:16.577+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:16.647+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:17.941+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:18.357+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:18.451+0000    [###################.....]  testfats_db.test_test  568MB/714MB  (79.5%)
2018-09-19T12:12:19.412+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:19.612+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:20.308+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:20.424+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:21.451+0000    [###################.....]  testfats_db.test_test  580MB/714MB  (81.3%)
2018-09-19T12:12:21.481+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:21.483+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:22.313+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:22.319+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:23.191+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:23.487+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:24.279+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:24.363+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:24.450+0000    [###################.....]  testfats_db.test_test  592MB/714MB  (82.9%)
2018-09-19T12:12:25.389+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:26.094+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:26.642+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:26.725+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:27.450+0000    [####################....]  testfats_db.test_test  602MB/714MB  (84.3%)
2018-09-19T12:12:28.434+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:28.436+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:28.640+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:29.106+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:29.787+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:29.791+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:29.800+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:30.017+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:30.450+0000    [####################....]  testfats_db.test_test  615MB/714MB  (86.1%)
2018-09-19T12:12:32.508+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:32.543+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:32.543+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:32.624+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:33.450+0000    [#####################...]  testfats_db.test_test  626MB/714MB  (87.8%)
2018-09-19T12:12:33.768+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:33.770+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:33.777+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:33.933+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:35.606+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:35.609+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:35.613+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:36.231+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:36.450+0000    [#####################...]  testfats_db.test_test  639MB/714MB  (89.5%)
2018-09-19T12:12:37.110+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:37.217+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:37.464+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:37.862+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:39.450+0000    [#####################...]  testfats_db.test_test  652MB/714MB  (91.3%)
2018-09-19T12:12:39.524+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:39.629+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:39.692+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:40.146+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:41.105+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:41.113+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:41.708+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:41.709+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:42.450+0000    [######################..]  testfats_db.test_test  664MB/714MB  (93.0%)
2018-09-19T12:12:44.564+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:44.595+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:44.909+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:44.911+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:45.450+0000    [######################..]  testfats_db.test_test  673MB/714MB  (94.3%)
2018-09-19T12:12:45.722+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:45.726+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:45.902+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:46.229+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:46.804+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:46.810+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:47.469+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:47.490+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:48.148+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:48.263+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:48.613+0000    [#######################.]  testfats_db.test_test  692MB/714MB  (97.0%)
2018-09-19T12:12:48.704+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:49.457+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:49.497+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:49.528+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:49.733+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:51.331+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:51.450+0000    [#######################.]  testfats_db.test_test  704MB/714MB  (98.7%)
2018-09-19T12:12:52.450+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:52.536+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:53.128+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:53.874+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:54.200+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:54.450+0000    [#######################.]  testfats_db.test_test  713MB/714MB  (99.9%)
2018-09-19T12:12:54.527+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:54.528+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:54.535+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:54.537+0000    error: Closed explicitly
2018-09-19T12:12:54.601+0000    [########################]  testfats_db.test_test  714MB/714MB  (100.0%)
2018-09-19T12:12:54.631+0000    restoring indexes for collection testfats_db.test_test from metadata
2018-09-19T12:19:31.668+0000    Failed: testfats_db.test_test: error creating indexes for testfats_db.test_test: createIndex error: EOF
```

Comment: did you try passing host in args? and if username & password required  that too?
also can you confirm the collection you trying to backing up. it should not be empty?
can you please confirm those?

Comment: did you check your logs?

Comment: @matthPen Sure /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log contains no relevant info. Like I said mongo prefers to keep silent on this.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty No, I did not. Sounds like a good idea, especially taking into account the fact that it's a mongo replica. The db has no password, so I believe I can omit the username and password here.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty well this time I specified the port and the host and it took considerably more time but like before the collection stayed the same, it did not get updated. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong but mongo doesn't give me any feedback somehow...

Comment: try with -vvvvv (verbose multiple time) option. Can you post your log?

Comment: @matthPen Sure, I've just done it.

Comment: so, seems like there is an error, something is not right in data in your bason file some how. as per your log.
can you try to import something else?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty yeah I could not figure out what it was exactly but then I ran the same command on another server and it worked like a charm. However I found out that it's also possible to run it with the `noIndexRestore` option. But in my case it worked without it. Thank you both for the help.